# Help identify blue flowers that look like Hydrangea

Tags: identification, flowers

### Here is the bouquet with this beautiful flowers.

[image]
Side:
[image]

### I found similar flowers in internet, but nothing about their name.

[image]
It looks like Hydrangea but has noticable differences, so I'm still searching.

### Hydrangea:

[image]

Comment: Zuz, I thought this would be a slam dunk.  Like you, the only pictures that looked right was the picture you sent and nowhere do they tell us the name.  The closest is Evolvulus pilosus.  But they all have a white center.  I get so OCD with ID.  Questions; are these flowers in the bouquet fresh or dried?  I've gone out to look for white flowers that might have been dyed as well.  Dying flowers is very common.  I've tried to use your keyboard for scale but it would help to know the size of these flowers, are the flowers you have fresh or dried?

Comment: I'm not convinced these are real flowers - can you try to damage  a petal to find out?

Comment: Also be helpful to see the stems of the flowers, if there are any - if these are fake, you can often tell by the stems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me preface this answer with:
 *Thank you. Now I have another plant on my garden wish list.*

This beauty is a comparatively new cultivar of **Hydrangea macrophylla with filled blooms**.

It is based on Japanese breeder Irie Ryoji's [H19-17 or H. macrophylla "Love"](http://www.newplantsandflowers.com/lovely-pink-hydrangea-from-japanese-breeder/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed:%20NewPlantsAndFlowers%20(New%20plants%20and%20flowers)). Dutch breeders Van Klaveren developed the "[You & Me](http://www.vanklaverenplant.nl/?p=hortensia&hcat=pothortensia's&categorie=77&product=56)" series, the blue version is [You & Me 'Together'](http://www.hydrangeatogether.com).

They are also available as cut flowers, e.g. [from here](https://www.trianglenursery.co.uk/41205-hydrangea-macr-you-and-me-together):
[image]

So yes, this is a real plant, not a silk replica.

Comment: My internet's driving me mad, seems to have gone on a go slow for Christmas, so  I can't access any of the links you've given to have a look. Should I ever be able to do so, I'll get back - I did actually google the other day for  new hybrids of hydrangea, but nothing came up... but still not convinced, the blooms in the pic don't seem to have stems and don't seem to be in water

Comment: Yep, Hydrangea You and Me Together (dear oh dear, what a name)...vote given!

Comment: Grins, dang good job Stephie!  What a hoot!! But Bamboo is right.  How the hell can flowers stay looking so good without water?  And still that wouldn't allow for more than a day or two!  I think these are silks and that new hydrangea either was the model or it was modeled after these silk flowers.  Amazing what we can do with ONE  picture and a few words of explanation.  This site really needs to address this topic.  Far more people would be able to make use of our feedback if we had a more automated system at the very beginning, just naggin'...grins!!

Comment: @stormy: Erm, this is *one* stem and the photo is taken straight from above. Of course you can't see a stem or vase. My florist (and I) would use a small tube-like vase (a narrow  jam jar or bottle) and nestle it inside the arrangement of dry twigs. It's absolutely doable and if done right, one could even exchange the live flowers without disrupting the whole thing.

Comment: @ZuzEL, I guess a few users here are looking forward to your definitive report on the big "silk or real" debate once you get back to the office ^_^

Comment: Yup. This side view shows there.must be a pot or receptacle for water. I guess it's real after all. Will retract my answer.

Comment: @Brenn don't. It's totally feasible and valuable.

Comment: Still looks like silk to me.  Need to see the water vessel.  @ZuzEl please send a picture by carefully opening the twigs or taking a flower and squeezing it.  You gotta understand how tough it is to make decisions and answers by pictures!!  We are all in a snit to know for real these are real flowers.  Yes, that new hydrangea could do this could be these flowers but they would only last at the most 3 days without constant water.  Silks can look spectacular and last forever, which florists try to promote using silks/dried flowers.  Who replaced the water?  I was a florist for a year, snickers!!

Comment: Guys, flowers turned out to be real, unfortunately I can not sent any picture cuz it's not in front of me, but I got the answer about if it's real or not.

Comment: After 4 years I want to add a little bit more info. **Hydrangea Macrophylla “romance blue”** looks exactly the same as we were looking for.

Answer (score 6):

This is a "silk", dried and dyed or otherwise replication of a Hydrangea.

Comment: I do think they are fake and are a replication of the newbie Hydrangea...or viseversa.  The Hydrangea promoted to replicate these silk flowers.  So much fun these detective ID's off one photo and a few words or explanation.

Comment: We used to carry a line of silks from France at a nursery I worked at that were unbelievably realistic unless felt by hand. Oh. They often came in a "nest" of silver or glitter painted twigs such as this.

Comment: @stormy I added side photo

Comment: Brenn...hold on.  Until we get to actually see these flowers in very large tubes of water or a tube, they still might be dry or silk.  Really, silks were amazing!!  Fresh flowers aren't that worshiped by everyone.  AND, if they are fresh they are in the process of drying...this little bit of water in a tube, supported by these twigs is the perfect way to dry hydrangeas!  i just gotta know for sure...

Comment: @Brenn - good point about the dead twigs - that's what makes me think this is more likely a silk replica too,but we'll never know unless we see inside the bouquet....

Comment: After 4 years I want to add a little bit more info. **Hydrangea Macrophylla “romance blue”** looks exactly the same as we were looking for.